# Specifying an Item Separator in Python

Tags: python

I am new to programming in Python and using 2.7.5 version. I am running the following python statement

```
monthly_pay = 5000.0
annual_pay = 12*monthly_pay
print 'Your annual pay is $',format(annual_pay,',.2f')
```

when I run it, there is a space between $ sign and the amount 60,000 and I don't want that space so I have tried to use

```
monthly_pay = 5000.0
annual_pay = 12*monthly_pay
print ('Your annual pay is $',format(annual_pay,',.2f'), sep= ' ')
```

but shows an error on IDLE. I don't understand why. Can anybody help?

Also I tried similar statements like 
`print('One', 'Two', 'Three', sep='')` but again as above it shows me an error

Comment: You are on python2.x.  At the top of your file put `from __future__ import print_function`.  This will let you use the Python3.x syntax, although you will have to convert all `print` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2, you'll need to concatenate the strings yourself if you want to avoid a space:

```
print 'Your annual pay is $' + format(annual_pay, ',.2f')
```

The code you tried:

```
print('Your annual pay is $', format(annual_pay, ',.2f'), sep= ' ')
```

will work in Python 3, since `print` was turned into a function, and as such, can take keyword arguments (like `sep`), but since you're in Python 2, you have to go about it a different way.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) `format()`, but you'll get the result you want by using the string's `format()` [method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format).

```
print 'Your annual pay is ${}'.format(annual_pay,',.2f')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `comma` adds the space. You can can use the String Formatting syntax using `%s`

```
>>> print 'Your annual pay is $%s' % format(annual_pay, ',.2f')
Your annual pay is $60,000.00
```